# Quiero tomar los datos de cada etiqueta?

Tags: javascript, html5, jsp

Quiero que al hacer click en cada botón de cada `div` generado me tome los datos en las que están, el precio y el nombre, pero al generarse la pagina, todos los botones devuelven la información del primer `<div>` generado por el `foreach...`

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function data(){
         var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML;
         var precio = document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML;

         alert(nombre+" "+precio);
     }
 </script>
```

Entonces este es el bloque que se genera dependiendo la cantidad de objetos `GPU` que hayan:

```
     <c:forEach items="${gpus}" var="gpus"> 
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="${gpus.url}" alt=""></a>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a id="nombre" href="">${gpus.nombre}</a>
              </h4>
                <h5 id="precio">$ ${gpus.precio}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">${gpus.descripcion}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="button" onclick="data()"id="info" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carrito</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

       </c:forEach>
```

[[image: Alert con la descripcion del primer bloque que contiene una 1080[1]]

[image: Bloquee con la primera tarjetas]

Comment: Explícate algo mejor, no logro entender lo que necesitas, o el error que obtienes.

Comment: Tomar los datos que estan en las etiquetas con el id "nombre"' y "precio", pero al hacerlo todos los botones devuelven el mismo valor, del primer <div> osea en el que se encuentra la 1080, absolutamente todos y cada uno de ellos, he probado con $(document).ready pero en ese caso solo el div en el que se encuentra la 1080 funciona, el cual es el primer div que se genera cuando comienza el foreach del JSTL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, como tienes varios elementos con los nombres (nombre y precio) no deberías usar `id`, deberías usar `class` ... **Recuerda que el `id` es un identificador único e irrepetible en el sitio**

Ahora lo que debes hacer es capturar la información perteneciente al botón al que se le dio click, de la siguiente manera:

**Ejemplo funcional (usando JavaScript nativo)**

```js
function data(event){
    var nombre = event.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('nombre')[0].innerHTML;
    var precio = event.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('precio')[0].innerHTML;
    

    alert(nombre+" "+precio);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="" alt=""></a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
                <a class="nombre" href="">Producto 1</a>
            </h4>
            <h5 class="precio">10.000</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Descripci+on producto 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="button" onclick="data(this)" id="info" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carrito</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="" alt=""></a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
                <a class="nombre" href="">Producto 2</a>
            </h4>
            <h5 class="precio">20.000</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Descripci+on producto 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="button" onclick="data(this)" id="info" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carrito</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Como debería de quedar tu código**

```
<c:forEach items="${gpus}" var="gpus"> 
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="${gpus.url}" alt=""></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a class="nombre" href="">${gpus.nombre}</a>
                </h4>
                    <h5 class="precio">$ ${gpus.precio}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">${gpus.descripcion}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="button" onclick="data(this)" id="info" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carrito</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function data(event){
    var nombre = event.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('nombre')[0].innerHTML;
    var precio = event.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('precio')[0].innerHTML;


    alert(nombre+" "+precio);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Exactamente bro, Gracias !!!!! Funciono !!!!, La verdad debo dedicarle mas tiempo al JS !!!

Comment: Te lo hice de esta forma "larga" para que conocieras el [parentNode Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp), el resto de la lógica es prácticamente la misma que tenías, saludos !

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que, **en `HTML` el `id` de cada elemento se espera que sea único e irrepetible**.

Para cada uno de los "productos" de tu página estas creando varias veces elementos con `id` "nombre" y "precio", y al obtenerlos mediante `document.getElementById` solo obtienes el primero que se creo con dicho `id`.

Una solución es concatenar a estos elementos el `ID` de cada "producto" y así obtener 'ids' únicos para cada elemento `HTML`

### Ejemplo

Suponiendo que dentro de `${gpus.id}` esta el `ID` de cada "producto", entonces, el código sería este:

```
<c:forEach items="${gpus}" var="gpus">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="${gpus.url}" alt=""></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a id="nombre${gpus.id}" href="">${gpus.nombre}</a>
        </h4>
        <h5 id="precio${gpus.id}">$ ${gpus.precio}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${gpus.descripcion}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="button" onclick="data(${gpus.id})" id="info" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carrito</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</c:forEach>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function data(id) {
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre' + id).innerHTML;
    var precio = document.getElementById('precio' + id).innerHTML;

    alert(nombre + " " + precio);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias hermano !! Lo tendré en cuenta para demás implementaciones.

Comment: @DanielL.Estevez, si bien la respuesta de @Camilo es válida, lo que a mi no me gusta, es que: 1. Esta atada a la estructura del diseño (`markup`), si mañana agregas un `div` al `button` dejaría de funcionar. 2. El nombre de las `class` no respeta el formato del resto. 3. `event.parentNode` no es el estándar, deberia usar [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#Properties)

Comment: Tu idea me parece mas dinámica realmente,ya que utiliza ${gpu.id} como fuente del evento, y no modifica en nada la idea original que tenia de "Como implementar la captura ?"